# How to enable "New-GlobalAddressList" command when connecting with certificate through Azure Active Directory application?

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory

I need to enable "New-GlobalAddressList" command in Exchange online module. In order to enable it user needs to be assigned "Address list" role in Exchange Admin center [MS docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/new-globaladdresslist?view=exchange-ps) .

Problem is that I connect to this Module through an Azure Active Directory application using certificate, not user..

`Connect-ExchangeOnline -CertificateThumbprint "XXX" -AppId "XXX" -ShowBanner:$false -Organization “XXX”`

My question is: how to assign that "Address list" permission to AAD application? I can't find such permission in "API Permissions"..

Comment: I have looked up almost all the documents and have not seen how to grant the "address list" permission to the application.According to the description of the document: `This cmdlet is available only in the Address Lists role, and by default, the role isn't assigned to any role groups. To use this cmdlet, you need to add the Address Lists role to a role group (for example, to the Organization Management role group).`

Answer (score 1):

I have looked up almost all the documents and have not seen how to grant the "address list" permission to the application.According to the description of the document: `This cmdlet is available only in the Address Lists role, and by default, the role isn't assigned to any role groups. To use this cmdlet, you need to add the Address Lists role to a role group (for example, to the Organization Management role group).`

Therefore, I think whether you are using users to connect to ExchangeOnline or applications to connect to ExchangeOnline, if you want to use `New-GlobalAddressList`, you can only add the "Address List" role to the role group.